# Bounded sum of reciprocals of primes.

Tags: analytic-number-theory

How can one adapt Apostol's proof that the bounded sum of the reciprocals of the first primes is $$\log\log x + C + O(1/ \log x) $$ to conclude the same about $$ \sum\limits 1/(p+1) $$ ? I just need a little push.

Comment: The difference between $\displaystyle\sum_{p\le n}\frac{1}{p}$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{p\le n}\frac{1}{p+1}$ approaches a constant as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Perhaps you could push a little harder.

Answer (score 1):

The approach above does not provide the explicit value of $C_0$ in the estimate $$\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{1}{p+1}=\log \log x+C_0+O(\frac{1}{\log x}).$$
Here is how to remedy this:
We have
$$
\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{1}{p+1}=
\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{1}{p}-
\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{1}{p(p+1)}
.
$$
The estimate
$$
\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{1}{p(p+1)}
=
\sum_{p}\frac{1}{p(p+1)}
+O\left(\frac{1}{x\log x}\right)
$$
shows that 
$$
C_0=C-\sum_{p}\frac{1}{p(p+1)}
$$
where $C$ is defined by
$$\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{1}{p}=\log \log x+C+O(\frac{1}{\log x}).$$

Comment: +1 Deleting mine. I treated that $C$ as an error term, but that doesn't make much sense for here $O(1/\log x)$ is surely in that role.